# Convert integer to a binary value

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript, convert

I want to display the given number in binary format. For example 78 -> 1001110

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site isn't a code-writing service, and it works best when you have a specific issue and can show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and what research you've done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any existing algorithm and implement it in the apex. For example

```
public static String intToBinary(Integer n) {
    String s = '';
    while (n > 0)
    {
        s =  ((Math.mod(n, 2)) == 0 ? '0' : '1') + s;
        n = n / 2;
    }
    return s;
}
```

usage:

```
System.debug(intToBinary(78));
```

Result:

> |DEBUG|1001110

---

thanks for @sfdcfox in the comments. Here is an optimized version of it

```
public static String intToBinary(Integer n) {
    String s = '';
    while(n != 0) {
        s = (n & 1) + s;
        n >>>= 1;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: My previous comment had a bug, too. The function should have been `public String intToBin(Integer n) { String s = ''; while(n != 0) { s = (n & 1) + s; n >>>= 1; } return s; }` the `>>=` should have been `>>>=`.